# Keys are not working propely

Tags: keys

Hi people I am new to ubuntu and currently have ubuntu 12.04LTS installed it has been quite nice but the thing is when i tried to type " it will show @ instead and when i tried to type @ it shows " this instead and when i type this # this shows up £ ! Please help!

Comment: It's quite possible you have default USA keyboard map as opposed to UK map.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `System Settings`, and choose `Keyboard Layout`. There you can visually see if it matches to your actual keyboard. I suppose you have a wrong layout set.

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByR3uTWe1yI).